# System detects digital output when headphones plugged in, audio does not work

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I'm on a MacBook Pro (2013) running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. The speakers work as usual, but when I plug in headphones, the audio stops working. When I remove the headphones, the speakers work again as before.

With headphones plugged in, the only output device available is "Digital Out - Optical digital-out port", and when I try to change the volume there is a disabled symbol (and no volume bar is displayed).

I have tried rebooting, using a different set of headphones, resetting the PRAM, and cleaning the port, all to no avail. I do not see a red light in the port as many other questions have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a pair of OEM Apple headphones (from an iPhone or so)? There are some cases, that only the OEM headphones work, and 3rd party do not. If they do work, try the following:

- Plug your headphones back in.
- Play a bit of sound through them (e.g., a song), then stop the sound.
- Make sure Preferences is quit.
- Launch Preferences and open the Sound pane.
- While the Sound pane is open and set to Headphones, pull out the headphone plug from the jack.
- It will reset itself to "Internal Speakers" and you are good to go.

Comment: I ended up getting a replacement through my IT dept. Thank you for the replies though, hopefully they'll help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Please try plugging the heaphone jack more than 20 times fast in and out. I had the same issue, it might be, that the spring, that detects a plugged in headphone, is defective and it detects the wrong kind of plug.
Or maybe the following will help you: Under Sys Pref> Sound > Click on Internal speakers.  Then at the bottom set audio port for "sound output."

Comment: If you're going to do that, do it with the machine switched off.

Comment: No luck on the first suggestion. The second one I cannot do as the speaker output disappears when the headphones are plugged in. I think it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin : Why should the machine be turned off? This should not harm any Soft/Hardware in my opinion. It's a common "repair" technique amongst Apple premium service providers.

Answer (score 0):

Daan's answers above work for probably a majority of people with this problem, but if you're like me, and those fixes stop working after a while or don't work at all, it's possible to actually break the circuit that erroneously switches you to the Digital Output and prevent it from activating, leaving you with headphones and speakers and normal.

The solution, which originally comes from stin17 on [this MacRumors thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-optical-out-wont-turn-off.239287/page-4), is intimidating but uncomplicated. We simply want to interrupt the line between the audio codec IC on the logic board and the little switch in the headphone jack by removing a component in between. This is usually a small resistor on older models, and after the Retina MBPs I believe it is an inductor.

If you can correctly identify your logic board model number (physically located on the logic board itself, usually a 6- or 7-digit number; for example, my 2012 MBP with a 2.3GHz i7 is a *model* A1286 and *board number* 820-3330-B) and find the boardview and schematic, you'll be able to find a resistor in line with the digital output switch, which, when removed, will prevent the audio codec IC from reading the digital switch. This **permanently disables** the optical digital/TOSLINK audio output, and you **should not** do this unless you are certain you've found the right resistor! However, if you're sure you know which components you're looking at, it takes about 10 seconds to scrape the tiny surface-mount resistor off the logic board with an x-acto knife.

If you have an A1286 macbook, it is likely R6805, which you can find in schematics and boardviews; this part number will certainly be different on other models. On my logic board, the circuit we want to interrupt is labeled AUD_PORTB_DET_L. Later models, after Retina I believe seem to rename this circuit to AUD_CONN_TIPDET_1 or AUD_CONN_TIPDET_2; I'd guess TIPDET_1 is headphone detection and TIPDET_2 is TOSLINK detection, but I'm not positive since I don't have one of those boards to check. **Make sure you double check these on your particular model!** I can't guarantee that R6805 is the one to get, but that's a good place to start.

The result here is that the digital switch inside the headphone jack remains physically stuck, but it no longer matters as it cannot complete its circuit to erroneously tell the audio IC that there is a TOSLINK plug in the jack. Again, optical digital audio output over TOSLINK **does not work after doing this, unless** you replace the resistor and go back to the current "digital out" problem, but it sounds like you don't need optical digital audio output. This is straightforward and familiar for some, for others it's new and terrifying! I started learning my way around schematics and boardviews because of this exact problem. If you feel up to the task and you don't need TOSLINK audio output from your headphone jack, this is the most reliable and elegant fix when the other temporary methods fail.